# Check Html tag exist inside another Html tag using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, tags, html-agility-pack

I have three Html strings

1.

```
 <h1>
    <table>...</table>
    </h1>
```

2.

```
<h1>
<p>
<table>...</table>
</p>
</h1>
```

3.

```
<h1>
    <p>
<div>
    <table>...</table>
    </div>
    </p>
    </h1>
```

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to check whether h1 tag contains table tag like this

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/h1").Where(i => i.ChildNodes.Any(c => c.Name == "table"))
```

But this condition only works for 1st html string. For 2nd and 3rd Html string which condition i should apply?

I want condition which check whether table tag exist inside h1 tag? and table tag can be anywhere inside h1 tag.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the XPath syntax instead of Linq.

Use double slash "//" to select a relative path
In your case:

```
var tableNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1//table")
```